# How to show information in plotly on click?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

The default in plotly is that information is shown when hoverd over. I would like to only show information when an object is clicked on. Is this possible? The following is an example in R using the plotly package and taken from [here](https://moderndata.plot.ly/visualizing-geo-spatial-data-with-sf-and-plotly/):

```
library(plotly)
library(mapview)

data(franconia, package = "mapview")

plot_ly(
  franconia, 
  split = ~NUTS_ID,
  color = ~SHAPE_AREA,
  alpha = 1,
  showlegend = FALSE
)
```

How would I make plotly to show the name of the names of the regions only when clicked on?

Comment: Did you get your code to even plot the map? I have attempted to replicate this example and it will not plot 'franconia'.